# MultiDex application: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when a library is enabled

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using `Android Studio 3.1.2` & `Gradle 3.1.2` & `minSdkVersion 19` & `compileSdkVersion 26` and tested on Emulator running `Nougat` and my smartphone running `Oreo` and getting this exception once i start the app

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.***.***.****, PID: 16366
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.***.***.***.view.application.MyApplicationClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.***.***.***.view.application.MyApplicationClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.***.***.***-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.***.***.***-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.***.***.***-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:802)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.***.***.***.view.application.MyApplicationClass" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.***.***.***-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.***.***.***-2/lib/x86, /data/app/com.***.***.***-2/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:992)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:796)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5377) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

- `MyApplicationClass` extends `MultiDexApplication`
- I'm registering the class in the manifest file `android:name=".view.application.MyApplicationClass"`
- I'm enabling MultiDex in `gradle.build` with `multiDexEnabled true`
- I'm using `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'` for backward compatibility
- **I'm using [SOASTA mPulse library](https://docs.soasta.com/beacon-api/#android) for performance monitoring**

When I **enable this library** using `apply plugin: 'com.soasta.mpulse.android'` the exception happens, **otherwise the app works fine**.

I tried many solutions but none is working:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
- http://myhexaville.com/2017/03/10/android-multidex/

Been trying to fix this for 2 days now, any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score -1):

And I find the solution is add 
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: No this isn't the solution!